# Find id or tag of a view that is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android programming.  I'm using recyclerview + cardview + adapter to show a list of items (image + text).

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){


          String k = user.getLid(); // from pojo class
           startviewact(k);

        }
    });
```

I'm using the above code to find which item is clicked. But now i want to know which view type is clicked in this item (i have an image and text).

Can anyone provide me with some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: none of those answers are working and my questions is different, im specifically asking for solution to work in adapter

Comment: Are you saying that you have different `View` types in the `Adapter`; i.e., overriding `getItemViewType()`? If that's what you mean, you can call `getItemViewType()` on the `ViewHolder` to get its type.

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of the argument v

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.textView:
            //your code here
            break;
        case R.id.imageView:
            //your code here
            break;
    }
}
```

`v` is the View that was clicked. So check its id.
Change `textView` and `imageView` with the ids of your views.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

          if ( v instanceOf TextView) {
           // code for textview
          }
         if ( v instanceOf ImageView) {
           // code for imageview
         }

          String k = user.getLid(); // from pojo class
           startviewact(k);

        }
    });
```

Comment: instanceOf is not working, showing in red?? Any help?

Comment: use instanceof operator provided by Java